# htaccess: Remove .php extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a file named Show.php

i want to remove .php extension of this, and if someone requested /Show.php, redirect him to without .php extension Page.

This is my htaccess but it does not redirect user to without extension page.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^Show\.php$
RewriteRule ^Show\.php$ ./Show [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Show$ ./Show.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REQUEST_URI`, unlike the `RewriteRule` expression, begins with a leading `/` but your expression begins with `^Show`. Simply adding the leading slash should do the job. Everything else looks correct.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Show\.php$
#-------------------------^^^^^
RewriteRule ^Show\.php$ Show [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Rewrite to Show.php rather than ./Show.php
RewriteRule ^Show$ Show.php [L]
```

Comment: It not worked. /Show.php  not redirected to /Show. i'm sure my first RewriteCond is wrong. but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @HosseiN Does the request also have a query string as `/Show.php?thing=123` ? If so, the RewriteCond should not have a `$` anchor