# How Create SEO friendly search with php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

this is a search script which I'm using in my site. This search file is saved in home directory as search.php

```
<?php


    $searchTerm = trim($_GET['q']);
    $searchlink = str_replace(" ","_",$searchTerm);
    $id = trim($_GET['q']);
    if($searchTerm == "")
    {
        echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
        exit();
    }

    $host = "localhost"; //server
    $db = "db"; //database name
    $user = "user"; //dabases user name
    $pwd = "ss1122"; //password
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable As a JOIN mytable2 As b ON a.mycolumn=b.mycolumn WHERE a.mycolumn LIKE '%$searchlink%'";
    $results = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    print "<div class=\"box-title\" style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #efefef; padding-bottom:10px; margin-bottom:5px;\">You Searched for \"$searchTerm\"</div>";
    print "<div class=container><div class=container-top><div class=container-bottom>";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1)
    {
        $output = "";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
        $output .= "<h4><a href="$row['mycolum'] . "/>Search result</a></h4>";  

        }
        echo  $output;
    }
    else
        echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchlink;

    ?>
```

When ever user search something say "free" the link becomes `http://mysite.com/search.php?q=free`

While I want this search link to become `http://mysite.com/search?q=free`

How can we do this with .htaccess or some other method?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615097/php-seo-friendly-urls?rq=1

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323920/htaccess-remove-php-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(search)\.php(\?q=[^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(search)/?$ /search.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Worked well. But one problem, link contains repeat keyword i.e, search?q=free&q=free

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess` with rewrite rule for eg

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search?q=(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This does not work, because RewriteRule's do NOT include the query string! The query string needs to be matched with a seperate `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.