# Removed .php file extension using htaccess but now my php code is no longer working?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the .php file extension for a page hosted online.

I managed to remove the .php file from my URL however some of my php code within my page is no longer working... the php code is now appearing on the page as iof not compiled... the page is called blog.php

my .htaccess is as follow:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog\.php$

RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ blog[R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Rewrite to Show.php rather than ./Show.php
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [L]
```

This is from a post I found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323920/htaccess-remove-php-extension)

The page loads fine, however the PHP code within the page is just being displayed on the browser instead of being compiled.

My php code being:

```
<?php include('includes/config.php'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php
                try {

                    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
                    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                        echo '<div class="blog_p">';
                            echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                            echo '<p class="dtm">Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                            echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
                            echo '<p class="rm_btn"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';                
                        echo '</div>';

                    }

                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            ?>
```

I dont get why it isnt showing in the browser as a php file?

Anyone?

Just for info, without any .htaccess in the directory, the blog.php file works perfectly fine.

Comment: And why the MySQL tag?

Comment: bad habit... one rarely goes without the other. Probably shouldn't have included it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also checkout this [link](https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/). Your php missing the .php extension may cause it to not be rendered by the php engine. Try adding html files to be parsed by the php engine.

This is what my rewrite looks like, feel free to try it out

```
<Files .htaccess>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for that.

Just tried it, but the issue remains.

Comment: @Grem357 Also checkout this [link](https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/)  Your php missing the .php extension may cause it to not be rendered by the php engine.  Try adding html files to be parsed by the php engine.

Comment: That worked a treat! It is working now! Great link, thanks for that! :)